# Is this history-related question suitable for Skeptics.SE?

Tags: discussion

["Did Albert Einstein really recieve this rejection letter"](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/30501/did-albert-einstein-really-receive-this-rejection-letter) - I found this on History.SE, and I feel that it's sufficiently *skeptics*-related as it is questioning the authenticity. Would this be a suitable candidate for moving to this SE? I am quite new to these processes and obviously as a non-mod I wouldn't have the power to do so.

Comment: Funny, I was inspired to come here again after reading that question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some questions can be on-topic on several sites in the Stack Exchange network. This one looks like a good example. As such there is no need to migrate it.

Sometimes, some sites attract different types of expert, making a migration advantageous, but this question has accrued some highly rated answers on History.SE, so again there is no motivation to migrate it.

In general, if you think a question should be migrated:

- If you have [3000 rep](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/close-questions), use a Close vote on the source site.
- Otherwise, flag for moderator attention on the source site.

The Skeptics mods cannot steal a question *from* History.SE.

Answer (score 1):

The question would be welcomed at skeptics.stackexchange but if the history.stackexchange folks want to keep it, there's no need to move it. It only has to be moved if they don't want it and don't believe it belongs to their site.

Comment: Fair enough. So is the process that the history.se folks start the migration? Does the question need to be flagged to start the process?

Comment: Yes, but as far as I can see the question isn't necessarily off-topic on history.se so they might not want to move it.